# Xmonad is ignoring my keybinding for switching workspaces

Tags: linux, xmonad

I am new to Xmonad and am having trouble changing the binding combination to switch workspaces. I have changed the default modMask to mod4Mask with `modMask = mod4Mask` in `myConfig`. I have then configured `mod1Mask` shown below which I hoped would have the workspace change by pressing `mod+[0-9]`,

```
    --
    -- mod-[1..9], Switch to workspace N
    -- mod-shift-[1..9], Move client to workspace N
    --
    [((m .|. mod1Mask, k), windows $ f i)
        | (i, k) <- zip (XMonad.workspaces conf) [xK_1 .. xK_9]
        , (f, m) <- [(W.greedyView, 0), (W.shift, shiftMask)]]
    ++
```

However, after restarting with `mod+q` (that I see restarts), I still can only switch workspaces with `mod+[0-9]`

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: You set `modMask` to `mod4Mask` (the "Windows" key), yet in your code you are using `mod1Mask` (the "Alt" key). Which key do you refer to, when you say "restarting with `mod+q`" or "switch workspaces with `mod+[0-9]`"?

Comment: Yes, I want the Windows key to be modMask and therefore WindowsKey+q will restart Xmonad which is how things are working now. However, I want left ALT `mod1Mask` to be the key used in switching workspaces which seems `xmonad.hs` is ignoring.

Comment: Then using `mod` for both in your description is a little bit misleading. Nevertheless, your code snippet looks fine. Maybe there's some other error elsewhere in the file. Have you checked the logs? What's the output when recompiling in the terminal?

Comment: I get this when I recompile:
```
~$ xmonad --recompile; xmonad --restart; 

XMonad will use ghc to recompile, because neither "/home/xxx/.config/xmonad/build" nor "/home/xxx/.config/xmonad/stack.yaml" exists.
XMonad recompiling (forced).
XMonad recompilation process exited with success!
```

Edit: I don't think formatting works well in comments

Comment: I guess that `mod` in the file here refers to `modMask`. Why doesn't it say `modMask` instead of `mod`? It seems confusing to be inconsistent. But I'm still getting used to XMonad. Hopefully these things will be clearer over time.

Comment: Re "Why doesn't it say `modMask` instead of `mod`?": In Haskell, `--` starts a comment, so change that to whatever you want (especially considering that you simultaneously use the wording of `mod+q` to refer to the Windows key). As for your actual problem, though, your snippet (at least in this extent, and according to what I can spot) doesn't really contain anything else to target, sorry.